# How can I get the current color of an element that is mid-transition in Chrome / WebKit?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, css, webkit

I have a color transition in chrome.  I would like to retrieve the color at any point using JavaScript.  Currently, I'm accessing .style.color in the DOM, but this only gives me the target value.

EDIT this was answered a while ago, an example for chrome can be seem here http://nu11.co.uk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getComputedStyle([element],"").getPropertyValue([property])` *should* return the in-transition color (but I haven't checked it.)

Comment: I think I love you. getComputedStyle( [element], null ).color